# Programmatically trigger an event after binding delay

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am programmatically binding to a textbox which is generated based on properties within a class. This all works, but I would like to have an event triggered when the binding completes.

I have tried adding this:

```
// EventBus is a static class with a bunch of different static events
textBox.KeyUp += (sender, e) => EventBus.OnLayerActionChanged(this);
```

However, this causes the event to fire too soon since the binding hasn't completed.

This is what I am doing to create the `TextBox`. What can be done to trigger this event after the binding delay is executed?

- **property** - This is the info about one of the properties in the class `ActionA`
- **action** - This is the instance of the class that `property` belongs to
- **panel** - This is a `StackPanel` that the input is added to

```
    private void AddNumber(PropertyInfo property, MyAction action, Panel panel) {
      var textBox = new TextBox {
        Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0)
      };

      var binding = new Binding(property.Name) {
        Delay = 300,
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
        Source = action
      };

      textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
      panel.Children.Add(textBox);
    }
```

Here is an example of an action (All of which have different properties):

```
  public class ActionA : MyAction {

    [Input] public double PropA { get; set; } = 25;
    [Input] public double PropB { get; set; } = 12.5;

  }
```

Comment: Maybe you should change the binding type to explicit like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8805854/2029607) SO question.

Comment: Would that make `Delay` useless?

Comment: If you handle it explicitly you can use Task.Delay(300) if you really want to.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement my own binding by removing the binding entirely and adding a custom `KeyUp` event that is triggered after a delay by starting/stopping a timer.

```
    private void AddNumber(PropertyInfo property, MyAction action, Panel panel) {
      var textBox = new TextBox {
        Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0)
      };

      var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer { Interval = 300 };
      timer.Tick += (s, e) => {
        timer.Stop();
        var val = Convert.ChangeType(textBox.Text, property.GetValue(action).GetType());
        property.SetValue(action, val);
        EventBus.OnLayerActionChanged(this);
      };

      textBox.KeyUp += (sender, evt) => {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();
      };

      panel.Children.Add(textBox);
    }
```